# Still able to recover files after running cipher.exe on windows 7

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, deletion

After running `cipher.exe` on my entire C: drive, I'm still able to recover deleted files using [recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva). In fact, doing a before and after, I see no discernible difference in the files that are able to be recovered after using `cipher`.

According to the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/use-cipher-to-overwrite-deleted-data),

> the cipher /w:c:\test command causes all deallocated space on drive C: to be overwritten.

Any idea why cipher doesn't seem to work as I expect?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried, but in NTFS, "deallocated space" and "metadata" is not the same thing. Try to recover a file: is it recoverable, or is it garbage? (I would agree that not deleting the name of a file is still a security risk, and freed files metadata should be considered deallocated space, but maybe Microsoft thinks differently).

Or maybe (please do not be offended, it's a thing that happens to everybody: it happened to *me*) you copied the example from the docs, and `/W:C:\TEST` will only erase the unallocated space hanging on the "TEST" node, **not** the entire drive C: (that would be `cipher /W:C:\`). Even if the TEST directory does not exist, cipher will still look for it for a long time, given the impression of being doing *something* while actually it is doing absolutely nothing.

TL;DR use `SDelete` or the Tools section in Piriform's CCleaner instead of `cipher /w`. Just in case.

Comment: No, I didn't copy and paste. I did the root of c:/ (No offense taken). However, I think you may be on to something with the metadata theory, as I didn't actually recover the file. I had the same thought. I will test this and get back with you asap.

Comment: That's correct. The filename and pointer exists in the Master File Table (MFT). Deleting a file marks the MFT entry as available but does not wipe it. The MFT itself is never deallocated so wiping doesn't touch it. What's more, very small files *(typically under 900 bytes but could approach 1.4K)* are stored directly in the MFT, so they will never be wiped. Then there's **Shadow Volumes**.